# Here Maps slow loading tiles

Tags: maps, loading, here-maps-rest

I'm using (or try to) Here Maps for my iOS Application. I just downloaded the example project. Just including the map and a few markers (Same problem without markers).

The problem is, when I try to zoom in our out with the pinch gesture (using the build in function from hereMaps) the tiles turn white with the "here"-Logo on in and it takes several seconds to load the real maptile. Thats waaaay to slow. Compare it to google maps, there is not a single loading tile. I did not changed anything. Don't know what to change anyway, its just a few lines of configuration code.

The question is: Is that the normal behaviour? Is there a few to speed it up?

Testet with several WiFi's. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2FRY.png) attached.

Thanks! :)